# SQL Server SSMS: how to get row numbers for a batch

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

In SSMS, how can I get SSMS to show row numbers for a batch? I can get row numbers for a query window, but that does not help when an error occurs in batch statement. This feature would help me a lot to find errors from my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

double click on the error in the message tab and it will move the cursor where the error statement is